# как правильно произвести обработку нажатий клавиш мыши?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Что необходимо произвести обработку нажатий клавиш мыши с обновлением иконок в приложении.

Как должно работать:

- Запускается приложение, горит иконка 1, нажимаешь левой кнопкой мыши, срабатывает код для этой иконки.
- Нажимаешь правой, запускается выпадающий список, с похожими иконками, у каждой код одинаковый за исключением одного параметра.
- При нажатии левой кнопкой мыши на иконку выпадающего списка срабатывает код для нее, и иконка изначальная меняется на ту, которую применил.

Если нужно что-то уточнить, или кусок кода предоставить, пишите, отвечу. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Нашел почти то что мне нужно, но перевести на Pyqt5 не получается.

```
#
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qt, QtCore
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    left_click = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    right_click = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.left_click.emit()
        elif event.button() == Qt.Qt.RightButton:
            self.right_click.emit()
            
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        #super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.btn = Button('Нажми меня')
        self.btn.left_click.connect(self.left_click)
        self.btn.right_click.connect(self.right_click)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
    def right_click(self):
        print('right click')
    def left_click(self):
        print('left click')
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: можно ли произвести обработку сигнала кнопки таким образом? self.pbg1.clicked.connect(lambda: functions.fnc1(LEFT OR FIGHT))   (под LEFT OR FIGHT я подразумеваю функции которые будут определять нажатие клавишей левой или правой, где-то такое видел)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class BaseButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BaseButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText("Button")
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.window().setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.window().list_widget.show()            

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        pass
        
        
class MyListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))
        self.setSpacing(5)
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('myapp')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('img/qt-logo.png'))
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold))    
        
        self.list_widget = MyListWidget()
        self.list_icon = ["lena.jpg", "Ok.png", "katya.jpg", 'img/qt-logo.png', 'im.png',
            "lena.jpg", "Ok.png", "katya.jpg", 'img/qt-logo.png', 'im.png']
        for i in range(10):
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(f'item {i}')
            icon = QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(self.list_icon[i]).scaled(100, 100), 
                QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
            item.setIcon(icon)
            self.list_widget.addItem(item)
        self.list_widget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.item_Pressed)  

        self.btn = BaseButton(self) #QPushButton("Physics", self)        
            
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.list_widget.hide()

    def item_Pressed(self, currentRow):  
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(self.list_icon[int(currentRow)]))
        
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.resize(500, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Поправил под PyQt5:
все огонь!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    left_click = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    right_click = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.left_click.emit()
        elif event.button() == Qt.Qt.RightButton:
            self.right_click.emit()
            
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        #super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.btn = Button('Нажми меня')
        self.btn.left_click.connect(self.left_click)
        self.btn.right_click.connect(self.right_click)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
    def right_click(self):
        print('right click')
    def left_click(self):
        print('left click')
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, отвечает ли мой ответ на ваш вопрос и был ли он вам полезен ?

Comment: однозначно полезный, но иконки не распознались ни jpg ни png.

Comment: вы пробовали мой пример? и заменили изображения в `self.list_icon = ["lena.jpg", "Ok.png", "katya.jpg", 'img/qt-logo.png', 'im.png',
            "lena.jpg", "Ok.png", "katya.jpg", 'img/qt-logo.png', 'im.png']` на свои с нужными путями ?

Comment: Заменил на свои, путь в той же директории. начинают отображаться после клика, нажатия левой и правой кнопкой мыши не распознаются.